# Is there a way to calculate average based on distinct rows without using a subquery?

Tags: sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, window-functions

If I have data like so:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    10 |
|  1 |    10 |
|  2 |    20 |
|  3 |    30 |
|  2 |    20 |
+----+-------+
```

How do I calculate the average based on the distinct id WITHOUT using a subquery (i.e. querying the table directly)?

For the above example it would be (10+20+30)/3 = 20

I tried to do the following:

```sql
SELECT AVG(IF(id = LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id), NULL, value)) AS avg
FROM table
```

Basically I was thinking that if I order by id and check the previous row to see if it has the same id, the value should be NULL and thus it would not be counted into the calculation, but unfortunately I can't put analytical functions inside aggregate functions.

Comment: Any reason you do not want to use sub query?

Comment: The outer query will have other parameters that need to access all the data in the table

Comment: @User You should really ask the actual question which concerns you.

Comment: I updated the question, not sure if I'm being specific enough

Comment: Please don't change your data after others have already answered.

Comment: I don't understand...you want me to be more specific but I can't edit the question? What would you like me to do then?

Comment: This issue related to the `outer query` is something you should not hide from the question.  Explain the real problem.  Let's see if others might have suggestions not previously considered.   For instance: Certain databases can do what you asked.  :)

Comment: first of all, tag your DBMS and the version please

Comment: @User . . . This looks like an XY problem.  You should ask a new question that is clear on what you really want to accomplish rather then settling on an approach such as "calculate the average without a subquery".

Comment: Is there a case that for a certain id there are 2 different values?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this without a subquery.  I would use:

```sql
SELECT AVG(avg_value)
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(value) AS avg_value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RANK AS (

Select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS RANK

FROM 
TABLE
QUALIFY RANK = 1
)

SELECT 
AVG(VALUES)
FROM RANK
```

Answer (score 0):

> The outer query will have other parameters that need to access all the data in the table

I interpret this comment as wanting an average on every row -- rather than doing an aggregation.  If so, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) over () as overall_avg
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way,
Simply use distinct inside the avg function as below :

```
select avg(distinct value) from tab;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d156/2/0

Comment: OP wants distinct IDs, not values.

Comment: Consider two different IDs with the same Value.

Comment: @Serg You are right, I didn't read the question well